# Fetch an SNI certificate from https with openssl

Tags: openssl, sni

I know I can print out a site's certificate with OpenSSL like this:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect sni.velox.ch:443
```

But on some sites it doesn't work because they rely on SNI.

Is there a way to send an SNI request via openssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443 -servername example.com
```